# Goutte disable Guzzle caching

Tags: php, symfony, goutte, guzzle

I am having a problem with Goutte, or actually it's Guzzle part of Goutte.

Guzzle does automaticly cache every GET call, i have tried to disable it, but i can't really get it working.

As you can see here, i am parsing the cache parameters directly into the Guzzle constructor.

```
use Goutte\Client;
use Guzzle\Http\Client as GuzzleClient;

$client = new Client();

$client->setClient(new GuzzleClient('/', array(
    'curl.options' => array(
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt',
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0
    ),
    'params.cache.override_ttl' => 0,
    'params.cache.default_ttl' => 0,
    'params.cache.revalidate'   => 'always'
)));
```

However this does not make any changes. As of the documentation for the cacheplugin(see: http://guzzlephp.org/guide/http/caching.html)

This code:

```
echo $client->getClient()->get('/')->getParams()->get('cache.override_ttl');
```

Should output the current value of the cache.override_ttl, this does not output anything.

I believe it must be something about the Goutte wrapper, that i overlook. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: By default Goutte is not doing any caching. What behaviour is making you think otherwise?

Comment: Goutte doesn't use any cache either, how do you know that **every** GET call is being cached?

Comment: Have you tried something like : ```$request->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');```